# Property doesn't exist on one type in union of two types based on a generic

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, typeorm

I have a method:

```js
async findUserById<T extends Partial<UserData>>(
    id: number,
    select?: (keyof UserData)[]
  ) {
    if (!select) {
      select = ["id", "name", "email", "picture", "bio"];
      const user = await this.findOne(id, { select });
      return user as UserSafeData;
    }

    const user = await this.findOne(id, { select });
    return user as unknown as T;
  }
```

It decides what to return based on select parameter and if a generic is passed it sets the return type to it, if no select parameter it returns `UserSafeData` type.

1- Generic type like:

```js
const user = await this.userRepository.findUserById<{ picture: string; }>(userId, ["picture"]);
```

2- UserSafeData which is:

```js
type UserSafeData = {
    id: number;
    email: string;
    name: string;
    picture: string;
    bio: string;
    tasks: Task[];
}
```

Now, when I try to do:

```js
const user = await this.userRepository.findUserById<{
      id: number;
      email: string;
      refreshToken: string;
}>(userId, ["id", "refreshToken", "email"]);


if (!user?.refreshToken) ...
```

When trying to reference `refreshToken` I get this error:

```
Property 'refreshToken' does not exist on type 'UserSafeData | { id: number; email: string; refreshToken: string; }'.
  Property 'refreshToken' does not exist on type 'UserSafeData'.
```

This is because `refreshToken` is not in the `UserSafeData` type but it should work because it exists on the generic type.

So, how to solve it?

> Note: why I am doing this is because I am trying to achieve a strongly static typed database calls because if I select only one entity column, typescript will still assume that I have all of the entity model

Comment: Use user defined type guard. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYBYxw).

Comment: This is a bit dodgy... I'd split that up into two separate functions, one with `select`, and one without.

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine What is that, how & where to use it?